# API Rest with SF3, return null

Tags: rest, symfony

I'm working in an API rest with Symfony, FOSRestBundle.

i have a route who return some informations about the user, and i don't know why the return is always null in Postman.

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/user/{id}", name="api_user_informations")
 * @ParamConverter("user", class="UserBundle:User", options={"id" = "id"})
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request, User $user = null)
{
    if (!$user):
        return new JsonResponse([
            "code" => Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND,
            "error" => "No user found with this id."
        ]);
    endif;

    return new JsonResponse($user);
}
```

What is wrong with this ?

config.yml

```
fos_rest:
routing_loader:
    include_format: false
view:
    view_response_listener: true
format_listener:
    enabled: true
    rules:
        - { path: '^/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 'json' }
```

Thanks boys :)

Comment: Because I'm curious: how does your `User` entity look like? If your `user` object is always null, something did not work properly using ParamConverter.

Comment: The user entity is simple and when i dump the user after the paramConverter, i have a result. It's just return new JsonResponse($user); is null ...

Comment: Then I guess your serialization does not work properly. You could try `return new \FOS\RestBundle\View\View($user, 200)` or extend your controller  with `extends FOSRestController` and use `return $this->view($user, 200)`.

Comment: It's working now :) Thanks you !